# How to keep track of variables in if statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement, variables

I am having trouble keeping track of a variable that is assigned by a random number generator. I am trying to generate two random numbers with different ranges and based on the numbers generated with update the score or don't and then tell the user if they win or loss based on a set of rules.

I have attached the code below so you can see what I am talking about but I basically need help with the variables roll1 and roll2, thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.Random; // import random number class
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class
public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //rules and variables 
    System.out.println("Welcome to lucky dice, the computer will roll 2 dice...");
    //int roller1 = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1); //instance of random class
    //int roller2 = (int )(Math.random() * 20 + 2); //instance of random class
    //Random rand = new Random();
    int total = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int max = 11;
    int min = 1;
    int max2 = 21;
    int min2 = 2;
    
    //create a loop to keep rolling until the user wins or looses 
    while (num <= 20 && total >= -50 && total < 150){
        System.out.println("Are you ready to roll?");
        Scanner reply = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        String answer = reply.nextLine();
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (answer == "yes"){
            int roll1 = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;//instance of random clas
            int roll2 = rand.nextInt(max2 - min2) + min2;//instance of random clas
           
            
        }while(roll2 % 2 == 1){
            int roll2 = rand.nextInt(max2 - min2); //instance of random clas
        }if (roll1 > roll2 || roll2 > roll1){
            total = total + roll1 + roll2; //keep track of score and tell user
            System.out.printf("Your roll was: " + roll1, roll2 + ".");
            System.out.printf("Your score is now " + total + ".");
            num = num + 1;
        }else if (roll1 == roll2){
            total = total + roll1 + roll2; //keep track of score and tell user
            System.out.printf("Your roll was: " + roll1, roll2 + ".");
            System.out.printf(" Your score is now " + total + ". ");
            num = num + 1;
        }
    }if (num > 20){
        System.out.println("You lost!");
    }else if (total >= 150){
        System.out.println("You won!");
    }else if (total >= -50){
        System.out.println("You lost!");
    }
        
   
  
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep tracking a variable?" I mean, what do you want with the tracking?

Comment: `answer == "yes"` No! this is not how to compare Strings in Java.

Comment: What exception are you getting with this program? Please edit your question to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a variable in the if block. Declare the variable level above

```
 ...
    String answer = reply.nextLine();
    Random rand = new Random();
        int roll1 = 0;
        int roll2 = 0;
    if (answer.equals("yes")){
        roll1 = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;//instance of random clas
        roll2 = rand.nextInt(max2 - min2) + min2;//instance of random clas  
    }...
```

or move there all declare

```
...
int min = 1;
int max2 = 21;
int min2 = 2;
int roll1 = 0;
int roll2 = 0;
....
```

Comment: DV for `if (answer == "yes")`

Comment: Okay. But how can you compare variables further if they are declared in the local block?

Comment: I think that you have answered that correctly, but please do not copy-paste wrong code into your answer.  Please correct it and I will remove my DV  and give you and upvote.

Comment: @ScaryWombat you keep on saying that do not compare strings with `==` and you do not give people a solution. You could just tell that `String` is an object and for objects we use `.equals(anotherObject)`  to check equality...

Comment: I am very sorry @Renis1235

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't know if this was ironic or not, but in case it was not, there is no need to apologize. Just gave a suggestion. Happy coding :)

Comment: Ironically, I do not understand irony.  @Renis1235